# how to set the clicklistener in a listview,it is extends Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, clicklistener

Here is the main code:

```
public class CollectionListActivity extends Activity  {
    ListView listView;
    String[] titles={"标题1","标题2","标题3","标题4"};
    String[] texts={"文本内容A","文本内容B","文本内容C","文本内容D"};
    int[] resIds={R.drawable.icon_list_view,R.drawable.icon_list_view,R.drawable.icon_list_view,R.drawable.icon_list_view};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.setTitle("BaseAdapter for ListView");
        listView=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
        listView.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(titles,texts,resIds));
        //--here how can i set a clicklister???
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already **`setOnItemClickListener`** available for ListView.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
             // do your operation here
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes,i change the code like this:listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });

Comment: but still doesn't work,i run the app,click the list item,then throw an exception--12-03 07:57:34.258: E/AndroidRuntime(681): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout